# Prove that there exists no sequence of independent events $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A_i) = \frac{1}{2}$ for all $i

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be any probability triple where $\Omega$ is countable. Prove that it is impossible that there exists a sequence $A_1, A_2, \ldots \in \mathscr{F}$ of events which are independent and such that $\mathbb{P}(A_i) = \frac{1}{2}$ for all $i \in \mathbb{R}$.

We have a theorem:
Theorem 2.4. let $A_1, A_2, \ldots \in F$ for some $\sigma$-algebra $F$.
If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(A_n) = \infty$ and $ \{A_n; n \geq 1 \}$ are independent then $\mathbb{P}(A^*) = 1$, with $A^* = \limsup A_n$

I tried the following but I don't know if its correct.
We have that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} = \infty$, and also the $A_n$ are independent. However, $\mathbb{P}(A^*) = \mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n) = \frac{1}{2} \neq 1. Contradiction.$

Comment: Have you attempted something so far ? Do you have any idea of where to start ?

Comment: As a first attempt, try to work out what happens if such a sequence exist. If such a sequence exist, what can you do with it under the assumptions?

Comment: @Gâteau-Gallois i did